# Regular expression converting countdown timer to time

Tags: java, android, regex, eclipse

I am trying to convert a `CountdownTimer` into a correct time. I have tried regular expressions but I am always weak in these.

Here is my code.

```
Integer timeCount =  (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
int min = timeCount / 60;
int  sec = timeCount % 60;
textView.setText(min + ":" +  sec);
```

This code is showing me time `1:5` WHERE it should show me `01:05`. How can i do thaT.

Best Regards

Comment: regular expression for value formatting ... hmmm very interesting ... String.format should do the thing ... `textView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", min, sec));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems you are working just with numbers and strings, try the plain old brute and simple solution!

```
Integer timeCount =  (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
int min = timeCount / 60;
int  sec = timeCount % 60;
String textMin = (min < 10 ? "0"+min : min+"" );
String textSec = (sec < 10 ? "0"+sec : sec+"" );
textView.setText(textMin + ":" +  textSec );
```

Comment: or even better, what @Vikdor said

Answer (score 1):

following util function would help, right?

```
private String pad(int value) {
   return (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is strong but not suitable here tool. Use either `MessageFormat` or `System.out.format` instead.

Take a look on this article.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html